# Page stucked when href refering to a hash

Tags: html, hyperlink, refer

Hello I have 5 links that needs to refer to another section below in the same page (this sections are different depending the link and are shown using JS changing the displays).

The main issue is if a click 2, 3 or 4 times this links then the page get stuck 2, 3 or 4 times before I can scroll to top again. I mean, depending how many times I click (changing the displays) the page gets stuck that number of times too. Any ideas why this is happening and how to avoid it? I have tried a few things already but not getting it fixed. Thanks

```
<a href="#div">
<a href="#div">
<a href="#div">
<a href="#div">
<a href="#div">

 <div id="div"></div>
```

I have tried to use different names for every link and also changing the place of the div referred. Also changing div to span. Nothing different happened.

Comment: I don't think I understand your problem. How does _"the page get stuck"_? And why would you click multiple times on a link?

Comment: They show one div or another depending where you click, so you can change the displays with this links but they also need to scroll down a little bit to show the full div.

If I scroll to the top again, it gets stuck meaning I can not scroll to top until I scroll the same number of times I have clicked the links.

Comment: No, sorry, still cannot understand. Try to create an example, to illustrate your point. Currently the code in your question is weird, and *does not form valid code*.

Comment: Perhaps this is an artifact of the particular browser you're using? Who knows?

Comment: Apparently the issue was in a jquery script for the smooth scrolling. Thank you for your effort.